# How to find the value of this limit?

Tags: limits

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac
{3^{3n} \binom{2n}n ^2}
{\binom{3n}n \binom{6n}{3n}}
$$

I tried stirling's approximations but it makes the problem complicated . So please help me evaluate this problem . :)

Comment: Please typeset your question properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
for fixed $p$ when $m\to\infty$:
$$
\binom{pm}{m} \sim \frac{p^{pm} \sqrt p }{(p-1)^{(p - 1)m}  \sqrt{2\pi (p-1) m}}
$$

Comment: Can someone post detailed solution please ?

Comment: what did you do??

Comment: I used similar method that you had given hint on. But I couldn't find the ultimate answer. The answer is 2 but I am unable to find it.